Logistic Growth and the Use of Changing Units
I am having a hard time understanding how this unit change is used to get rid of the need to use specific values for $ N $ and $ \mu $. Could somebody explain? I just can't figure it out. Help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot.

The function
$ f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}: f(t, x) = \mu x(N - x) $
is given, where $ x $ describes the current population over time $ t $. $ N $ represents the maximum number of possible individuals living in the area and $ \mu > 0 $ is the growth rate. We define $ \tau $ as $ \frac{1}{N \mu} $.
Let the temporal evolution of the population be described by the differential equation $ \dot{x} = f(t, x) $.
The direction field is defined as $ V : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^2 $ with $ V(t, x) = (1, \mu x(N - x)) $. We draw $ V $ and utilize $ N $ as the unit for population, and $ \tau = N\mu $ as the unit for time, thus, we do not need to assume specific values for $ N $ and $ \mu $. The graph looks so neat:

